# Acessing Windows COM Objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, com, win32ole

I'm working with an API that has a COM-based interface. I've been using the [win32ole](https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole) module to instantiate the API, but one of the API functions requires a null value, and win32ole complains when a null argument is passed. I found this [workaround](https://github.com/Antony74/node-win32ole/commit/efc3d8feb9c1fb7c1845a1cc3f27da2f4d9873c8), but it just replaces a null value with an object. This allows me to pass null as an argument to the function call without win32ole complaining, but the function still fails because it requires a null value, which is now being replaced by an object in the workaround.

How can I pass a null argument to this API function?

```
api.Order_Import('import.xml', 'import.xsd', 0, false, '', '', null)
```

The first thing I tried was leaving off the last argument. This makes win32ole happy, but still causes the function to fail with the error message *Parameter 'loOptParam' must be null*.

Is there another module I can use besides win32ole for working with COM objects in node? My research didn't turn anything up.